# Error: SQLITE_MISUSE: bad parameter or other API misuse when creating table

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

Hello I have a project in NodeJS and I am having several issues with SQL Lite, I created the connection to a DB file and it seems okay but when I try to pass a query to create a table I get an error. Here is my code

```
import * as queries from "./SQLstm";
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
let db: any;

export async function initialize(){
    try{
        logger.info("Beginning connection");
        db = await connectToDB(); 
        db.serialize(function() {
            //Tables
            db.run(queries.parent_company);
            db.close()
        });
        //loadData();
    }
    catch(e){
        throw e;
    }
}

async function connectToDB(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try{
            const connection = new sqlite3.Database('../db/advertisers.db', sqlite3.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE);
            logger.info("Connection successful")
            resolve(connection);
        }
        catch(e){
            reject(e)
        }
    });
}
```

The query I am running is:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS __parent_company (    id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,    name TEXT NOT NULL);

Comment: your open flags are `undefined`, change `sqlite3.SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE` -> `sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE | sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE`

Comment: @Smitop, you enlightened me. I had only OPEN_CREATE in my code to create a new db file. But it failed. With your prompt I tried `OPEN_CREATE | OPEN_READWRITE`, it worked!